# Can I use material-ui-pickers without React?

Tags: material-ui

I'd like to use [material-ui-pickers](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui-pickers) without React. I have a Rails app (probably not relevant) and use Webpack as a module bundler (plus Yarn, Babel etc.)

Is it possible to use material-ui-pickers?

If so, how? I have a few text fields with a class "datepicker" and would like to open the Material UI picker on focus. I probably have to initialize a `MuiPickersUtilsProvider` somehow but couldn't get it to work.
Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

no, you cannot use this library without using react

Comment: Could you add a bit more explanation?

Comment: this component build to use with react framework 
when you try to use it without react like when you try to run ios app on android